# Connecting to LDAP Server from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directoryservices

I've been recommended to use `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` to be able to support connecting to LDAP servers other than Active Directoy [here](http://System.DirectoryServices.Protocols).
Unfortunately, I have not been able to search the directory properly. I'd like to be able to get a certain attribute for a user (e.g. `mail`). This is easily done in `System.DirectoryServices` namespace by using `DirectorySearcher` class. How can I achieve the same in `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace. Here's what I have so far:

```
var domainParts = domain.Split('.');
string targetOu = string.Format("cn=builtin,dc={0},dc={1}", domainParts[0], domainParts[1]);
string ldapSearchFilter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", username);

// establish a connection to the directory
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(
                                new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domain),
                                new NetworkCredential() { UserName = username, 
                                                   Password = "MyPassword" });
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
                targetOu, ldapSearchFilter, SearchScope.OneLevel, new[] {"mail"});
```

This code raises exception of type `DirectoryOperationException` with message `The object does not exist`.

I suspect there's something wrong with my `targetOu` and `ldapSearchFilter` variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this going against a non-Microsoft LDAP??

Comment: It should support both (e.g.  OpenLDAP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the main problem might be: `samAccountName` is a strictly Windows-only attribute that other LDAP servers won't know about.

So if you're going against a non-Active Directory LDAP, you should use something else for searching - e.g. `sn` (for surname or last name), `givenName` (first name), possibly `displayName`.

Another interesting option might be to use ANR (ambiguous name resolution) searches - see this [page on SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/ldap-filter.htm) roughly in the middle, where ANR is explained.

With ANR, you would write your query like this:

```
string ldapSearchFilter = 
   string.Format("(&(ObjectCategory={0})(anr={1}))", "person", username);
```

I also changed `ObjectClass` to `ObjectCategory` for two reasons:

- `ObjectCategory` is single-valued, e.g. only contains a single value (`ObjectClass` is multi-valued)
- `ObjectCategory` is typically indexed, and thus searches are typically a lot faster using `ObjectCategory`

Does this return the results you're looking for?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I changed the filter to use `anr` and `ObjectCategory`. The exception is gone. But `searchResponse.Entries` has 0 element. I'm querying an AD service right now. If I use `System.DirectoryServices` I get the mail attribute correctly.

Comment: @Kamyar: can you run the query in S.DS against OpenLDAP, too??

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot access an OpenLDAP server. But using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` and having the result in AD is a good step. I can test OpenLDAP later.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. there was something wrong in `targetOu` variable which caused the null result. after fixing and using `anr` everything works great.