# How to connect to an local ldap server using MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I´m trying to connect to an local LDAP server which i have set up using Apache Directory Studio. I´m using Visual Studio 2015 enterprise update 2 and MVC 5.

These are the two approaches I´m working with:

```
 public void ldap()
    {

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:10389");
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            var result = mySearcher.FindOne();

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exception = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException();
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            InvalidOperationException InvOpEx = new InvalidOperationException();
            Console.WriteLine(InvOpEx.Message);
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            NotSupportedException NotSuppEx = new NotSupportedException();
            Console.WriteLine(NotSuppEx.Message);
        }
     }
```

After var result = mySearcher.FindOne() is executed, an System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.DirectoryServices.dll occures, stating that an HRESULT E_FAIL-error was passed when calling a COM-Component.

I have no idea what that means and didn´t find something helpful using Google.

2nd approach:

```
try
        {
            LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("LDAP://localhost:10389");

            var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("cbrunato", "c2VjcmV0", "dc=example,dc=com");
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
            ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
            ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

After ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential) is executed, i get the error message "LDAP server is not available".

When i stop the ldap Server and run the program i get the same errors, so i guess i don´t get a connection to my ldap server with both approaches, but i have no clue why.

I´m very thankful for any help.

Update: Credentials are invalid exception

[Apache Directory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DJtg.png)

Strings used as username:

```
"uid=cbrunato"
"cn=Chuck Brunato"
"cn=Chuck Brunato,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"
"uid=cbrunato,cn=Chuck Brunato,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"
"uid=cbrunato,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Comment: E_FAIL is probably a permission issue. Is the identity of the appdomain allowed access? I don't even recall that ADS allowed for integrated security, I always had to provide networkcredentials.

Comment: I´m afraid i don´t understand. I have to admit I´m completly new to .NET.
Do you say that my application has no permission to connect to the LDAP server?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700115/connecting-to-ldap-server-from-net) seems useful as it shows how to provide credential, the answer is relevant because you're using ADS. You might need to read some more q+a on the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=directorySearcher+networkcredential).

Comment: Do you mean by ADS Apache Directory Studio or Active Directory Services ? I have read a lot on this ldap stuff and tried every different approach. When i use the ldap connection class i always get the error "The ldap server is not available"
My code is:

Comment: Yes, with ADS I mean the server.  if you run `netstat -a`  from a command prompt do you see port 10389 listed on your box? Is the firewall allowing connections? You can try that with telnet or putty.  Also please [edit] your question to include new details instead of burrying them in the comments.

Comment: I apologize, i have edited my question. netstat -a shows me TCP    127.0.0.1:3674         MyPC:10389  ESTABLISHED
When i enter my PC name as host and 10389 as port and try to connect with SSH the putty window opens but nothing happens. And i ran the program with my firewall turned off and got the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in the use of your `LdapConnection`.

First you need to set the LdapProtocol version and secondly you'll need basic authentication. The option Negotiate most often only works with Microsoft products. As you're using port 10389 you don't need SSL because 10636 is the SSL port.

This code works for me:

```
try
{
    // don't add LDAP://, the protocol is already known ...
    LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("127.0.0.1:10389");
    // notice we don't use the domain here
    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
          "uid=yourusername,dc=example,dc=com", 
          "yourpassword");

    // Apache Directory Server uses LDAPv3
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

    // 10389 is the plain port, no ssl needed
    //ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    // ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

    // let's not negotiate, only Basic is supported
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Now i can connect to the server. However, i get an exception after Bind(), that the credentials are invalid. I have added a picture of my Apache Directory Studio Server to the question. I tried different strings for the username (listed in the question). Could it be a problem that the password is SSHA hashed in ADS but in NetworkCredentials the password is provided as a normal String?

Comment: I can connect to the default admin account with uid=admin,ou=system and  the password "secret" which is saved as plain text

Comment: I would expect this `uid=cbrunato,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com` to work.  @DonKassube in my test the password was also stored as SSHA and I didn't need to change anything.

Comment: I have replaced the password in Apache Directory Studio with a plain text password and now it works. I´m very very thankful for your help, i have been working on this for like 2 weeks and the information on the internet varies a lot. Thank you very much !!!